# VScode remote SSH server fails to load the extensions

Tags: vscode-extensions, remote-server

Recently，my server encountered a strange problem. All the previously installed extensions were not loaded when logging in again.
Now we need to reinstall the extension every time we log in. There is no such problem before January 15. What is the reason?

We have tried to restart the server and reinstall the extension. The problem still exists. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9a6z3.png)
And I have checked the extensions path, all the extensions are still existed, but vscode doesn't load them, I did not find a similar situation on the Internet, is only I encountered this situation?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoO9S.png)

Comment: I am facing a similar where extensions won't load on the remote server.
The debugger also doesn't work remotely.
remove all remote vs code extensions without success  
`rm -rf ~/.vscode-*`